# Data structure conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree

How to convert the parent-relation array structure

```
const array = [{id: 1, parentId: 2}, {parentId: null, id: 2}];
```

to a 2D array where the first element of the nested array is the parent with no parentId,
and the last element is the child/leaf element.

ex:

```
const array_2 = [
  [{ id: 1, parentId: null}, { id:2, parentId: 1 }, { id: 3, parentId: 2}], [...], [...]
]
```

Comment: At some point, you'd need to use some sort of loops

Comment: I don't see the nested part if array_2. Can you rewrite the example or explain what you mean by nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to collect the paths from the root node of the tree to every node:

```js
const nodes = [
  {id: 1, parentId: 6},
  {id: 2, parentId: 1},
  {id: 3, parentId: 4},
  {id: 4, parentId: 6},
  {id: 5, parentId: 1},
  {id: 6, parentId: null}, // Root
  {id: 7, parentId: 2},
];

const nodeMap = new Map(nodes.map(node => [node.id, node]));
const paths = nodes.map(node => {
  const path = [{...node}]; // Or: const path = [node];
  let parentId = node.parentId;
  while (parentId !== null) {
    const parentNode = nodeMap.get(parentId);
    if (parentNode === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`No node exists with ID ${parentId}`);
    }
    path.unshift({...parentNode}); // Or: path.unshift(parentNode);
    parentId = parentNode.parentId;
  }
  return path;
});
console.log(paths);
```

Here is the example tree I used in the code above:

[image]

The paths from the root to every node:

```
Node-1: 6 <- 1
Node-2: 6 <- 1 <- 2
Node-3: 6 <- 4 <- 3
Node-5: 6 <- 1 <- 5
Node-6: 6
Node-7: 6 <- 1 <- 2 <- 7
```

...and this is what my code returns as a 2D JavaScript array.